# How to run shell command in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

How can I run shell command in javascript in code behind

I have this exe file on:

C:\Program Files\test.exe

that i want to run using javascript and I want to do it in codebehind or at least call this function from code behind.

The reason want to do it on code behind is that I have parameters need to pass them in the shell command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons you can not run commands from JavaScript.

If you are using JScript, then

```
var shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.Run("command here");
```

Comment: what is WScript? do I need to reference anything?
I need to put it in:

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

Comment: Here is an example  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function runDataReader(strpath) {
var shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.Run(strpath);
}
</script>

Comment: I guess you are happy with my answer then

Comment: how is that possible in linux?